# Express.js serving source maps and session

Tags: node.js, session, express, source-maps

I use ExpressJS and connect-mongo as a session storage. When including JavaScript files (at client side) that has "sourceMappingUrl" property, browser makes request to download it, and a zombie session in database is created. Removing "sourceMappingUrl" property fixes the problem, but it's not convinient and must be done at every JS script update. 
Is there any possiblity of serving *.map files through Express's static? Or maybe another method of fixing that?

Comment: Surely the easiest solution would be to make the router or static ignore .map files so that it's cause by the 404 error handler?